# Next.js image optimization for CSS background-image

Tags: reactjs, next.js, styled-components, image-optimization, nextjs-image

I want to use Next.js new feature Image optimization for background images in styled-components. Is there any way to optimize images without the `Image` component?

Answer (score -1):

Use kraken.io to optimise the image and use that image in the css background

Comment: thanks, but I don't wanna use a third party packagea. in fact i'm looking for built-in utility in `next/image`.